# How to find percentage in SQL from list of zeros and ones?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have result set like -

```
id achieved
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    0 
5    0
```

The Percentage should be 2/5 i.e. 40 %. How can I write a SQL Query to achieve something like this ? I would prefer not to use and nested select as the actual query is already doing quite a bit. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select avg(achieved) from ...
```

Note that you will have to use a group by function to include categories:

```
select gender, avg(achieved) from ... group by gender
```

Comment: +1 But if the datatype is `bit` you would need `AVG(CAST(achieved AS FLOAT))` or similar to avoid the error "Operand data type bit is invalid for avg operator."

Comment: Well this really doesn't give me percentage..I would probably want to do `100*avg()`..and will give me percent ! Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Misnomer you can do avg(achieved) * 100 if you want.  Is that what you mean?